# Application.Evaluate Does not work with SUMIF with ">" or "<" condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to use Application.Evaluate method for evaluating a Sumif formula in which the criteria is ">="

Following is the line of code I'm trying to get an evaluation of
So I have Order Numbers 1 to 15 in Cell E1 to E15, and their Respective Amounts in Cell F1 to F15.

In J1 the user inputs his Order Number. Amount over and above that order number will be totaled and displayed using Sumif Function.

Now I want to find this answer using Application.Evaluate

```
MsgBox( Application.Evaluate("=SUMIF(E1:E15, ">=" & J1, F1:F15)"))
```

I get greeted with True or False Message Box.
Now I am guessing the inverted commas in Sumif Function ie. `">="` is causing this problem. Hence to fix this, I amended the function to

```
 MsgBox( Application.Evaluate("=SUMIF(E1:E15, """">="""" & J1, F1:F15)"))
```

However now it returns 0, although there are values in it.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand a way around it

***Note: Please do not suggest to use any other function. I want to know it purely from `Application.Evaluate` perspective, as my further line of code depends on it. ***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All quotes inside the string must be doubled:

> `">="`

Should be

```
"">=""
```

Also:

> `Application.Evaluate`

will work on the active sheet, thus if the wrong sheet is active the sumifs will be done on the wrong sheet since no sheet names are provided in the formula itself.

Use

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate
```

Changing `"Sheet1"` to your sheet.

So in total:

```
MsgBox  Worksheets("Sheet1").Evaluate("=SUMIF(E1:E15, "">="" & J1, F1:F15)")
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of using double quotes, I previously used Quadruple Quotes. Don't know why I did that.
However now my problem is that I am picking this formula from a Cell. And in the cell itself the formula won't have double quotes.
This is what my piece of code says.
`MsgBox(Application.Evaluate(ActiveCell.Formula))`

I know that alternatively I could simply get the value by using `ActiveCell.Value` , but I have a reason to use `Application.Evaluate` as it is embedded in my further code.
Could you help me out here.

Comment: @x0nar that is a new question, please ask it in a new post.  But you need to use `replace()` to replace all the `"` with `""` before evaluating